# Error while deploying spring boot app on Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy Spring Boot app war on Jboss 7.1.1, but getting the error, Below is the server log. The same project runs fine on Spring Booot's internal Tomcat server.

```
17:00:18,569 ERROR [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS018202: Error calling onStartup for servlet container initializer: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(JBossContextConfig.java:148) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:115) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3845) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found like you've the double loading the core jars in your classpath.

You're probably having the  "org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator" in two jars.

You're having multiple versions of the springframework-core JAR in your project and/or container

It would be mess up during loading multiple jars with different versions at a time. It might be create conflict some older version of Spring with new version.

Comment: How to fix this?